# Access to object property or method from appended element jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, methods

I would like to know if it's possible to access an object property from an appended element. For example:

```
function anyFct(){
    this.div=$('<div ref="dv">').html('Hi').appendTo('body');
    div.animal='dog';
    div.yld=function(){
        alert(div.animal);
    };
    $('input type="text" value="anyIn" onclick="yeldAnimal(this);"').appendTo(div);
}

function yeldAnimal(obj){
    var actElement=$(obj).closest('div[ref=dv]');
    actElement.yld(); // I want that this yields 'dog'
}
```

and my HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="test" onclick="anyFct();">
```

So this is the logic: I create a div element when the button is clicked on. This div element has a text that when clicked on calls an external function that calls a method on its parent element (the div).

For many contextual reasons this must be the logic. I've already found a solution that is saving the object div in a global array and then search in all values of the array for the object that triggered the method. However, I would like to know if there is a 'cleaner' or correct way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible, and there are a couple of ways you could achieve it. The important thing you need to understand is the distinction between jQuery objects and actual DOM elements. When you use jQuery to create a `<div>` element, you create both; but what you end up with a reference to is the jQuery object - or, if you're chaining jQuery function calls, the result of the last function called. The DOM element, assuming you actually append it to the DOM, persists once that section of code has finished execution, but the jQuery object that's created will vanish when that variable goes out of scope.

When you execute some jQuery code later on to get a reference to your DOM element, it's referring to the same element on your page but it's a **different** jQuery object, so any custom properties you added to the original one won't be available. How do you get around that? **Set the properties on the actual DOM element.**

You can use the [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) method to access the underlying DOM element from a jQuery object, indexed from 0 (so `.get(0)` called on a jQuery object will return the first DOM element it references). With that you can then set your custom properties and later retrieve them, something like this:

```
function anyFct(){
    this.div=$('<div ref="dv">').html('Hi').appendTo('body');
    var elem = div.get(0); // the actual DOM element, the div
    elem.animal='dog';
    elem.yld=function(){
        alert(elem.animal);
    };
    $('<input type="text" value="anyIn" onclick="yeldAnimal(this);"/>').appendTo(div);
}

function yeldAnimal(obj){
    var actElement=$(obj).closest('div[ref=dv]').get(0); // also the div
    actElement.yld(); // alerts 'dog'
}
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gv2n4z5r/)

Note that I've made a few changes to your code in addition to adding in the usage of `.get()`, most notably correcting the syntax for creating the `<input type="text">` element in the first function.

Comment: Awesome!!! It's exactly what I wanted. I knew for the syntax for creating the input but I had problems to post. I was also exploring the get(0) but I only put it in the function not in the definition of the element. Another way that I found is to trigger an event:

  $(div).on('yld',function(e){alert(div.animal)});

and in yeldAnimal:

  var action=$.Event('yld',{})
  $(actElement).trigger(action)


Anyway, thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, most of this is not syntactically correct javascript and seems to be overly complicated. I believe if I understand what you're trying to achieve you want the following:

```
function anyFct(){
    var div=$('<div ref="dv">').html('Hi');
    div.animal='dog';
    div.yld=function(){
        alert(this.animal);
    };
    var element = $('<input type="text" value="anyIn">');
    $(element).click(function() {
        div.yld();
    });
    $(div).append(element);
    $('body').append(div);
}
```

Comment: No, as I said, the logic must be the same that I described, if not It would be too easy to do a event listener. Anyway, thanks for answering.